# How to override AbpAuthorizationResources localization in AbpAuthorizationModule

Tags: abp

I've successfully overridden few localization resources but for some reason cant do it for the Authorization localization.

as u can see from my code below in my domain shared module if successfully added localization from different modules but for authorization its not working.

for example

this is just a part of response

```
 "code": "Volo.Authorization:010002",
 "message": "Authorization failed! Given policy has not granted: SimplyAir.TimeTracks",
```

in my sr.json localization file ive added this localization string and translated it like the rest of modules. but localization from auth module is not working

```
{
    [DependsOn(
        typeof(AbpAuditLoggingDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(AbpBackgroundJobsDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(AbpFeatureManagementDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(AbpIdentityDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(AbpIdentityServerDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(AbpPermissionManagementDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(AbpSettingManagementDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(AbpTenantManagementDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(AbpAccountApplicationContractsModule),
        typeof(AbpAuthorizationModule), //i have added auth module
        typeof(AbpUiModule)
        )]
    public class SimplyAirDomainSharedModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void PreConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
        {
            SimplyAirGlobalFeatureConfigurator.Configure();
            SimplyAirModuleExtensionConfigurator.Configure();
        }

        public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
        {
            Configure<AbpVirtualFileSystemOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.FileSets.AddEmbedded<SimplyAirDomainSharedModule>();
            });

            Configure<AbpLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Resources
                    .Add<SimplyAirResource>("sr")
                    .AddBaseTypes(typeof(AbpValidationResource))
                    .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/SimplyAir");

                options.Resources
                    .Get<IdentityResource>()
                    .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/SimplyAir");

                options.Resources
                    .Get<AbpAuthorizationResource>() //ive included auth resource
                    .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/SimplyAir");

                options.Resources
                    .Get<AccountResource>()
                    .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/SimplyAir");

                options.Resources
                    .Get<AbpUiResource>()
                    .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/SimplyAir");

                options.DefaultResourceType = typeof(SimplyAirResource);
            });

            Configure<AbpExceptionLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.MapCodeNamespace("SimplyAir", typeof(SimplyAirResource));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @stefan,

I did successfully override the authorization localizations.

See: https://ibb.co/Bw7TxGd

Comment: link is broken, maybe you can provide link again

Answer (score 0):

First, check you database table [AbpPermissionGrants], check whether permission SimplyAir.TimeTracks has been granted. If not, I think you can update a new database and seed grant data again, check the permission grant data.

Comment: yes, mentioned permissions are present in that table